# opencv2 python3 imread with NoneType

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, filter, imread

I program in Ubuntu system with python3, opencv2. There are several images in the folder that need to be processed. When I use `imread`, `print(img.shape)` shows `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'`. And I checked the created images' size is 0 bytes. The strange thing is that there are some images can be read successfully, but some are NoneType. Thanks for your help.

```
import glob as gb
import cv2
import random
import os
import numpy as np

shared_path="/home/train_1/"
folder_list=["HTC-1-M7"]

for j in range(len(folder_list)):
    output_path=os.path.join("/home/test/",folder_list[j])

    camera_path= os.path.join(shared_path,folder_list[j])


    img_path = gb.glob(camera_path+"/*.jpg")
    counter=1
    for path in img_path:
        img = cv2.imread(path)
        print(img.shape)
        kernel = np.array([[-1,2,-2,2,-1],[2,-6,8,-6,2],[-2,8,-12,8,-2],[2,-6,8,-6,2],[-1,2,-2,2,-1]],np.float32)/12
        img = cv2.filter2D(img,-1,kernel)
```

Comment: check if `os.path.exists(path)` before `imread`

Answer (score 1):

It means that somewhere a function which should return a image just returned `None` and therefore it has no shape attribute.

Try `print(img)` to check if your image is None or an actual numpy object. You probably get this error because your image path may be wrong in a way. Make sure your path is completely correct.